# Record window audio with Python?

Tags: python, audio, window

Is there any way to record the audio of a single window and not the whole system audio? I couldn't find any solution for this problem and am using "sounddevice" to record the system audio, but the window audio itself would be way better!

It should work for Windows 10!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no correlation between windows and audio in Windows, so what you're asking for isn't possible. If you only care about a specific application, it _mightj_ be possible. But even then, it might not—e..g, in Edge or Chrome, there's probably per-tab audio, but not per-window.

Comment: If u mean window as in browser window , then its possible  using browser specific API's. However, most of these are (easily) done with JAVAscript. With python it may be stretch. See here for example : https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/04/record-almost-everything-in-the-browser-with-mediarecorder/